# Use variables as part of javascript code

Tags: javascript

Probably this question have been asked before. But I don't know how to ask it
I'll try explain it using this simple code.

```
 var x = document.getElementById("x");
 var y = "value";
 alert(x.y);
```

Hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying or what you're asking.

Comment: @kristjan he wants to do x.value, except y can be id or another tag element

Comment: Maybe you need `x[y]`

Comment: Do you want to access a property via Object?

Comment: I want to get x.value but using y